# How to call the svcutil exe from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, svcutil.exe

Is there a way I can call the svcutil exe from PowerShell? I need to automate this process through scripting.

Comment: It should just work if the containing directory is on your PATH.   If not, try `$env:PATH += ";C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0\Bin"`

Comment: I use svcutil to provision/deprovision the database. I have a UI that checks for any changes and if yes i update it manually. I am unable to write a script for the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can run any .exe file with this method :

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\FileAddress\File.exe'
```

it's very simple

Comment: I use svcutil to provision/deprovision the database. I have a UI that checks for any changes and if yes i update it manually. I am unable to write a script for the same.